# machine readable tag rev-list, their commits and annotations in one line

Tags: git

The best I've gotten is doing this for a given range of tags (FROMTAG -> TOTAG):

```
git rev-list --format=%d TOTAG..FROMTAG
```

Which gives out the following list:

```
commit 45091a7b32b23a0d1c68bd20bc9e9bf0b0fd2225
 (HEAD, FROMTAG, RFC-0099, master)
commit 2ebcb64b59260d3c6cc895c36a977a17c6fd416c
 (TAG-34, TAG-35 )
commit 6765e2617cd179942e374e439f92f1a35c4dcd03
 (RFC-00010)
commit 90221f270f25d18c79bf96598fff0fd1c9d6a9d8
 (RFC-0007, TAG-36)
```

Which is kindda messy to machine-parse. I'm looking to format it as a oneliner, maintaining the inverse sort:

```
45091a7b32b23a0d1c68bd20bc9e9bf0b0fd2225 HEAD this is the annotated message
45091a7b32b23a0d1c68bd20bc9e9bf0b0fd2225 FROMTAG another annotated message
45091a7b32b23a0d1c68bd20bc9e9bf0b0fd2225 RFC-0099 
45091a7b32b23a0d1c68bd20bc9e9bf0b0fd2225 master
2ebcb64b59260d3c6cc895c36a977a17c6fd416c TAG-34
2ebcb64b59260d3c6cc895c36a977a17c6fd416c TAG-35
6765e2617cd179942e374e439f92f1a35c4dcd03 RFC-00010
90221f270f25d18c79bf96598fff0fd1c9d6a9d8 RFC-0007
90221f270f25d18c79bf96598fff0fd1c9d6a9d8 TAG-36
```

But can't find how without looping thru a series of git commands and some scripting. Does git have any command that can do that?

Comment: Are you sure you get that output? --format=%d gives me:

commit 0e7c8efc9ab8fc1a1e3a945059212a41d150c265
commit 769cbbd6ec66714305799931cc04e92e489464d0
commit 2c9dbadb02f422d9836f1a52b71c6b8656331654

Comment: yes, as long as you have tags or any refs pointing to the commits, btw my git is version 1.7.6

Comment: Added an answer that might have something to do with this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some default configuration set for e.g. format.pretty. Check your local and global configuration with:

```
git config --list
git config --global --list
```

Comment: nope, I have no format.pretty configuration. This is just the way that tags are shown in all git installations I got.